# sed extract between two patterns

Tags: bash, sed

I need to extract the lines between "Timing exception" and "---------" from the report below, then output them to a file

```
Timing exceptions with no effect exception's 
report timing -paths [eval [::legacy::get_attribute paths <exception>]]
/designs/exceptions/path_groups/
-----------------------------------

Summary
 Loop-breaking cells for combinational feedback                   0
 Nets with multiple drivers                                       0
 Timing exceptions with no effect                                 5
 Suspicious multi_cycle exceptions                                0
 Outputs without clocked external delays                          0

                                                  Total:          5
```

I've tried 
`sed -n '/Timing exceptions/,/-----/p' filename`, but it always return

```
Timing exceptions with no effect exception's 
report timing -paths [eval [::legacy::get_attribute paths <exception>]]
/designs/exceptions/path_groups/
-----------------------------------
 Timing exceptions with no effect                                 5
 Suspicious multi_cycle exceptions                                0
 Outputs without clocked external delays                          0

                                                  Total:          5
```

I only want the upper 4 lines but I don't know how to get rid of the lower lines. Could anyone please help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Add `^` before `Timing exceptions` to indicate start of the line:

```
sed -n '/^Timing exceptions/,/-----/p' file.txt
```

You have `Timing exceptions` in two lines, one at first, and the other after the `----` line, so you are getting two chunks, one for first one upto the `----` line, and the other from the second `Timing exceptions` till end as there is no line with `----` afterwards.

We have used `^` before `Timing exceptions` so that we can only match the first chunk as in second chunk the `Timing exceptions` does not come at start of the line.

**Example:**

```
% sed -n '/^Timing exceptions/,/-----/p' file.txt 
Timing exceptions with no effect exception's 
report timing -paths [eval [::legacy::get_attribute paths <exception>]]
/designs/exceptions/path_groups/
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

heemayl's answer truly complete. However, here is an alternate approach using `awk`.

```
awk '/^Timing exceptions/,/-----/' infile
Timing exceptions with no effect exception's
report timing -paths [eval [::legacy::get_attribute paths <exception>]]
/designs/exceptions/path_groups/
-----------------------------------
```